# Mocking method that calls other methods

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a class

```
class X:

  def __init__(self, db):
    self.db = db

  def get_data_from_friend(self):
    return None

  def get_data_from_db(self):
    return self.db.get_my_db_data()

  def get_data(self):
    if data := self.get_data_from_friend():
      return data

    return self.get_data_from_db()
```

And I'm trying to test the `get_data` method, to validate that the calls inside of it are executed.

I have a test like this

```
def test_get_data(self):
  mock = create_autospec(X)
  mock.get_data()
  mock.get_data.assert_called_once() # <-- works
  mock.get_data_from_friend.assert_called_once() # <-- assertionError, not called
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: I'd suggest: don't. Don't mock parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing - test doubles are for _collaborators_ (in this case, perhaps the injected `db`). You should be free to refactor inside that class, as long as the observable behaviour through the public API remains the same, _supported by tests_ not constantly fighting them. Note also that `mock.get_data()` then `mock.get_data.assert_called_once()` is testing the test, not the implementation - there's no real code involved.

Comment: I have tests in place for the collaborators already (example is simplified), just wanted to cover this function to make sure an order of execution is followed in different scenarios

Comment: _"I have tests in place for the collaborators already"_ - yes, the collaborators also need to be tested separately, because using test doubles to replace the real implementation means they're not tested _here_. You should be able to test this _without_ mocking parts of `X`, but there's so little context left it's impossible to say how exactly.

Comment: I disagree, I don't care about the behaviour / implementation of the collaborators here (hence why they are mocked), all I care is that this function follows X steps on Y conditions.

Comment: So, are you wanting to test the method `get_data()`?

Comment: _"I disagree, I don't care about the behaviour / implementation of the collaborators here (hence why they are mocked)"_ - that's not a disagreement, you _shouldn't_ care about the collaborators, **that's why they're mocked**. But that's not what you're doing; you've mocked the thing you're supposed to be testing, then are somehow surprised when the test double doesn't do what the implementation does (of course it doesn't, that's the point of a test double - when you call `get_data` _on a mock_, it just records details of what it was called with and returns a canned value). Mock `db`, test `X`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yeah, I noticed that, I was under the assumption that autospec would somehow recreate behaviour too.

Comment: Autospec matches the _interface_, not the _implementation_: it's for _"ensuring that the mock objects in your tests have the same api as the objects they are replacing"_. There's no real `X` instance in your test at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your X class is correctly defined and accepts *dependency injection* so you can do something like this

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class X:

  def __init__(self, db):
    self.db = db

  def get_data_from_friend(self):
    return None

  def get_data_from_db(self):
    return self.db.get_my_db_data()

  def get_data(self):
    if data := self.get_data_from_friend():
      return data

    return self.get_data_from_db()

MOCK_DATA = "mock data"
def test_get_data():
    db_mock = MagicMock()
    db_mock.get_my_db_data = MagicMock(return_value=MOCK_DATA)
    assert X(db_mock).get_data() == MOCK_DATA
```